# variables on chart Tooltip

Tags: c#, charts

I want to show tooltip on my chart with some variables which changes every point of chart. For example,

```
 chart1.Series["alarm"].ToolTip = string.Format("#LEGENDTEXT\rSTOFK:{0}\rRSI:{1}\rMFI:{2}\rCCI:{3}",
                                               STOFK.ToString(),
                                               RSI.ToString(),
                                               MFI.ToString(),
                                               CCI.ToString()
                                              );
```

When I use this code, it shows variables are all "0 (zero)" but I am sure that my variables are different for every point.

How can I use this variable values stable at every point on chart?

I mean,
at 11.6.2017, STOFK=10 and
at 10.6.2017, STOFK=4 then,

I want to see on tooltip  STOFK: 10 at 11.6.2017 and
I want to see STOFK: 4 at 10.6.2017.

thanks.

Comment: Not sure how your variables are connected to the DataPoints. But if each needs a special value you will need to set the tooltips for each of the DataPoints.. No problem in doing it either when adding the points or after binding..  - Unfortunately there are no real expression or function calls allowed in the Chart labels/tooltip etc.. - When you got it working, feel free to self-answer the question. If you run into problems, expand the question and we'll help you out..

Answer (score 1):

You can actually edit the ToolTip property of any series in the Visual Studio Designer interface.

Select any chart, in the Series Collection Editor, select any series, you can edit the ToolTip in a pop-up Editor. There you will see you have access to your series data via a limit number of keywords at runtime.

In you case, STOFK is obviously not one of the keywords. However if it is one of you YValues of your Series, you can use the #VAL keyword. Unfortunately it is not supporting calculation/expression because it is a pure text editor. You most likely need to set ToolTip for each of the Series DataPoint, like @TaW said.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Series1.Points.Count; i++)
{
    DataPoint dp = Series1.Points[i];
    dp.ToolTip = string.Format("X: {0}\nY: {1}\nADDXY: {2}", dp.XValue, dp.YValues[0], dp.XValue + dp.YValues[0]);
}
```

Comment: STOFK is not my yvalues. it is one of mu variable in my code. my x values is date ande y values is result of STOFK+RSI+MFI+CCI

Comment: In that case you need to set the tooltip for individual data points shown above. It provides you the flexibility of doing the referencing/calculation based on the date.